# Set detected text darker than image - ccv

Tags: c++, c, struct, computer-vision

I want to change ccv swt default params in order to change alghoritm parameters. Some alghorithms offer searching text with brightness of screen both lighter and darker than text. I want to set this option in ccv swt for text to be darker than screen.

In order to do this, i want to play a little with **ccv_swt_param_t** struct a little.

Here is this struct in ccv.h:

```
    /* swt related method: stroke width transform is relatively new, typically used in text detection */
 typedef struct {
     int interval; // for scale invariant option
     int min_neighbors; // minimal neighbors to make a detection valid, this is for scale-invariant version
     int scale_invariant; // enable scale invariant swt (to scale to different sizes and then combine the results)
     int direction;
     double same_word_thresh[2]; // overlapping more than 0.1 of the bigger one (0), and 0.9 of the smaller one (1)
     /* canny parameters */
     int size;
     int low_thresh;
    int high_thresh;
     /* geometry filtering parameters */
     int max_height;
     int min_height;
     int min_area;
     int letter_occlude_thresh;
     double aspect_ratio;
     double std_ratio;
     /* grouping parameters */
     double thickness_ratio;
     double height_ratio;
     int intensity_thresh;
     double distance_ratio;
     double intersect_ratio;
    double elongate_ratio;
    int letter_thresh;
     /* break textline into words */
     int breakdown;
     double breakdown_ratio;
 } ccv_swt_param_t;

 extern const ccv_swt_param_t ccv_swt_default_params;
```

And in swtdetect.c i am changing source code in order to place my new struct. I was able to copy struct and pass it to interesting function, but i get message from swtdetect

```
swtdetect: ccv_basic.c:196: ccv_sobel: Assertion `fsz % 2 == 1' failed.
```

Here is how i changed swtdetect.c: 
It was:

```
(...)
        ccv_array_t* words = ccv_swt_detect_words(image, ccv_swt_default_params);
```

I played a little and changed:

```
    ccv_swt_param_t *ptr = malloc( sizeof( &ccv_swt_default_params ) );
//ptr->max_height = 600;
(...)
    ccv_array_t* words = ccv_swt_detect_words(image, *ptr);
```

All i want is to use best detection. I would like to set parameters for text to be darker that entire image.

Here, I copied somehow struct, it should be wrong, because assertion fails even if don't change any parameter.

[Here](http://libccv.org/lib/ccv-swt/) are docs for swt.

Comment: It's a very specialized question. You should add more relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

OK. 
I allocated memory for default const struct, but missed to assign it.

```
 ccv_swt_param_t *ptr = malloc( sizeof( &ccv_swt_default_params ) );
 ***ptr = ccv_swt_default_params;**
(...)
    ccv_array_t* words = ccv_swt_detect_words(image, *ptr);
```